# Correct way to obtain the git tree of a remote branch with libgit2

Tags: libgit2

I am trying to diff my HEAD with a remote branch using tree to tree comparison. To obtain the remote tree, I first tried using `git_tree_lookup` by passing the remote object obtained through `git_revparse_single`. This fails, even if I connect and fetch the remote beforehand.
However, if after checking, I cast the object pointer to a `git_commit *` and use `git_commit_tree` instead, it succeeds and returns me the remote tree.
Why does one way work and the other not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `git_revparse_single` on a reference will return you a `git_commit`, not a `git_tree`.  And you cannot cast a `git_commit` to a `git_tree`.

You are correct to look up the tree from the `git_commit` that you were returned using `git_commit_tree`.